# Reduce sensitivity in Swipeview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin I put SwipeView as an ItemTemplate in CollectionView:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <SwipeView>
        <SwipeView.LeftItems>
          <SwipeItem Text="Delete" />
        </SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
      </SwipeView>
    </DataTemplate>
  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Everything is fine except SwipeView is too sensitive to horizontal swipe motion. Instead of scrolling items in CollectionView I trigger swiping motion all the time. I have to make perfect vertical swipe if I want to scroll items. How to make it work the other way around? I want to reduce sensitivity of SwipeView so I can open it only if I perfectly execute horizontal swipe motion. I want scrolling occurs on any motion that is not recognized as perfect horizontal swipe.

Comment: Hi , you mean that vertical scrolling will affect the horizontal swipe motion ?

Comment: Hi! I want to scroll items. I put my finger on the screen and if I move it even slightest off the vertical direction SwipeView will capture all the inputs and won't let me scroll items - I can only move SwipeView shutter now. I'd like SwipeView don't capture any horizontal movements for, let's say, for 2 millimeters and if only horizontal movement is longer than 2 mm, then it captures inputs and do its thing.

Comment: Got it ! This should be a feature request actually . You can submit it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose) , then supporter will check that :-)

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Is this added as a feature request somewhere?

Comment: @Frank nope, I didn't report.